# Apache Kafka and Apache Storm Integration

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-storm

What is the difference between KafkaSpout and KafkaBolt object ? Usually KafkaSpout is used for reading data from kafka producers, but why we use KafkaBolt ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bolts in Storm write data. Spouts are Kafka *consumers*. You read from the broker directly, not from producers.

For example, you can use a Spout to read anything, transform that data within the topology, then setup a Kafka Bolt to produce data into Kafka